# How to know which port php5 is using I forgot the port number I used to install

Tags: php, ubuntu

I did not use PHP but had to install it for ganglia setup but could not access the php on calling localhost it shows IT Works .How do I know what is the port number .

Comment: PHP is not installed as a service on Ubuntu. It does not have a port number. So your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

The default port for HTTP is 80, so if in your browser you are using http://localhost and says "It works!" means it is working on port 80.

PHP is not a web server, you are probably using Apache. You can find its configuration files in /etc/apache2 folder. Look for apache2.conf, httpd.conf or ports.conf and find a line like "Listen (Port Number)"